# Blazor WASM and returning images only when authenticated

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor

I am currently writing a Blazor application that is using Azure B2C for Authentication and a .Net Web Api project for returning data.  Everything in regards to the Blazor app, the authentication and retuning/posting data is going great.

However I am unsure of the best way to approach returning an image from the Web Api ONLY if a user is authenticated. On previous .Net MVC applications I would use a generic handler and simply use:

```
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { // return image code }
```

Then on the page I could simply have something like

```
    <img src="/EmployeeImage?id=123" />.
```

This doesn't work with my current setup because the web api expects a token to authorise them so my thinking on approaching this at the moment is to use a Http.Getetc to return the image data to display.

Before I go off creating a new component and adding http calls to the web api etc so I can hopefully use this similar to:

```
    <ImageComponent Type="Employee" ID="123"></ImageComponent>
```

Is there a simpler, better approach?

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.
If you want guarantee the same "token in header" approach you need to use a component that trigger an http post and check the authorization level on the web api controller.

But you can also use a "mixed" approach appending the access token in the query string as a parameter.
Once you have the access token in your web api controller you can validate it against your authentication provider.
I use this mixed mode approach in various situation.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an example of this mixed approach?